# IntentService STICKY destroyed but service keeps logging data in Android 2.3.4

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, sticky, intentservice

I have an Android application.
In one activity I start a service like this:

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent(_context, HandlingService.class);
_context.startService(startIntent);
```

HandlingService is defined as follows:

```
public class HandlingService extends IntentService
```

Then inside HandlingService I have this:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, startId, startId);
    Log.v(ApplicationName,"HandlingService.onStartCommand");
    if ((flags & START_FLAG_RETRY) == 0){
        Log.v(ApplicationName,"Service is restarting");
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

and this:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent sourceIntent) {
    Log.v(ApplicationName, "HandlingService.onHandleIntent");
    sendSomething(); 
}
```

and lastly:

```
protected void sendSomething() {
    while (numberOfTry > 0) {
        numberOfTry++;
        Log.v(ApplicationName,"HandlingService.sending Something. Try# " + numberOfTry);
    }
}
```

numberOfTry starts in 1.

Then from the activity that starts the service, when I click on a cancel button I call this:

```
Intent stopIntent = new Intent(CallingActivity.this, HandlingService.class);
CallingActivity.this.stopService(stopIntent);
```

I see HandlingService.OnDestroy being called, but I keep seeing the log with "HandlingService.sending Something. Try# " and the increasing numbers.

Question: Why it keeps alive if I already stopped it with the call to stopService?

Thanks in advance! Guillermo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation for IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) explicitly states that you should **not** override `onStartCommand()` in your derived class. You are probably messing up the internal mechanics of the `IntentService`.

Either derive your class directly from `Service` or use the framework that `IntentService` already gives you (for starting/stopping itself).

Comment: But how will I make it STICKY if I don't override onStartCommand?
BTW, Why they make it possible to override it, but in the documentation they say "don't do it"???

Comment: `IntentService` has its own start/stop semantics. It starts a worker thread, handles the work it has in the queue, and stops itself when it is done. You don't need to override anything. It just works as documented. If you don't like the way it works, you just create your own service that extends `Service`. What is wrong with the start/stop semantics that `IntentService` already provides? What are you trying to do that isn't working with the default behaviour of `IntentService`?

Comment: The service needs to be continuously running until a condition is reached, I don't want to execute it just once.

Comment: Then you don't want to use `IntentService`. Just implement your own service that extends `Service`.

Comment: But isn't Service run on Main thread? I need to run my process on background. BTW, I'm calling super in onStartCommand, wouldn't that work properly despite I'm returning it STICKY?

Comment: `IntentService` has specific semantics. If you don't want the behaviour of `IntentService` then you shouldn't use it. If you want to have background threads then you need to start them and manage them yourself in your service. And yes, `onStartCommand()` runs on the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

from IntentService javadoc

**public void setIntentRedelivery (boolean enabled)**

Sets intent redelivery preferences. Usually called from the constructor with your preferred semantics.

If enabled is true, onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) will return START_REDELIVER_INTENT, so if this process dies before onHandleIntent(Intent) returns, the process will be restarted and the intent redelivered. If multiple Intents have been sent, only the most recent one is guaranteed to be redelivered.

If enabled is false (the default), onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) will return START_NOT_STICKY, and if the process dies, the Intent dies along with it.